# Отправление данных из формы в мерчант вебмани через

Tags: jquery, php

Есть ссылка (https://merchant.webmoney.ru/lmi/payment.asp) на которую посылает пост из формы.

```
<form name="donate_form" method="POST" action="https://merchant.webmoney.ru/lmi/payment.asp">
    Выберите способ оплаты:
    <select id="sposob" required>
        <option disabled selected> выберите... </option>
        <option value="0">Webmoney RU</option>
        <option value="1">Webmoney USD</option>
        <option value="2">Webmoney UAH</option>
    </select>
    Выберите услугу:
    <select id="price" required>
        <option disabled selected> выберите... </option>
        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="2">3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn">Оплатить</button>
    <input id="LMI_PLAYMENT_AMOUNT"  type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" value="">
    <input id="LMI_PAYMENT_DESC" type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_DESC" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_NO" value="">
    <input id="LMI_PAYEE_PURSE" type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYEE_PURSE" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_SIM_MODE" value="">
</form>
```

Экшен подходит, но значение полей можно изменить через исходный код. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: не совсем понятно,@FrostLee, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Answer (score 1):

В настройке кошелька вебмани есть поле Result URI (точно не помню как называется). Перед тем как совершить оплату, сверяются данные вашей формы и данные что будут в файле result.php. Посмотрите это видео: [Прием средств Webmoney на сайте](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqyGQqTyiAA). Очень хорошо все рассказано.